# AuthorizedKeysCommand of sshd_config getting called twice

Tags: linux, ssh, operating-system, openssh, sshd

AuthorizedKeysCommand paramter present in the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
The bash script which i called using this command is getting called twice.

The config file is as follows

```
#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/a.sh
AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody
```

And the bash script which is being called is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
logger "have fun"
if [ $# -eq 1 ];
then
python /opt/validate_user.py $1
exit $?
fi
```

When i see the logs at /var/log/messages, i see follwing

```
May 19 20:07:32 username vagrant: have fun
May 19 20:07:32 username vagrant: have fun
```

I am running Centos 6.7 and ssh version of the server is `OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013` and of the client is `OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011` and the command which i am using is `ssh -v vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222`
Also when i do `vagrant ssh` then the script is called only once

Edit: When i use the following command `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2200 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes  -i /Users/Vivek/new_file_1/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key`
 then the script is getting called once only
ssh log found using `ssh -vv`

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug2: bits set: 501/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: private key path (0x7fa4d9e00c20),
debug2: key: private key path (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Vivek/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp <fp>
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 127.0.0.1 ([127.0.0.1]:2200).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Fri May 20 12:16:10 2016 from 10.0.2.2
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
```

Some of the above log has been truncated since it was big

Comment: You say you're running "ssh -v...", so you're getting debug output from ssh. Could you edit your question to include the debug output for one of these sessions? Better, add another v: "ssh -vv ...".

Comment: @Kenster Added the log

Comment: Check server debug log (`LogLevel DEBUG3`).

Comment: @Jakuje When i use ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2200 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes  -i /Users/Vivek/new_file_1/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key this command then the script is getting called once only .

Comment: @Jakuje Can you tell me the possible reason ?